# How do I find the average case for the KthLargest alrorithm?

Tags: algorithm, average, analysis

I understand that the best case would be B(1). Will the worst case be W(n+1) since when searching the list, since you have to compare both sides of the last element. The main thing I am confused on is the average case for this algorithm.

```
findKthLargest (list, N, K)
for i = 1 to K do
    largest = list[1]
    largestLocation = 1
    for j = 2 to N-(i-1) do
        if list[j] > largest then
            largest = list[j]
            largestLocation = j
        endIf
    endFor
    swap(list[N - (i-1)], list[largestLocation] )
endFor
return largest
```

Comment: What do you mean by B(1) and W(n+1). I am not aware of this type of notations.

Comment: @Xenikh just meaning best case and worst case. The amount of work it would take for the best case is 1, meaning it was the first element. And for the worst case, it would be the last elements it found.

Comment: Okay, got it. Could have used the standard big-Oh notion.